# Hessian-Free instead of LSTM for Recurrent Net Machine Translation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Last year, Ilya Sutskever and collaborators came out with a [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf) about a recurrent LSTM net that learns sequence to sequence mappings for machine translation. It's somewhat surprising that the authors used LSTM instead of Hessian-Free to train this net since the first author was one of the innovators behind the development of Hessian-Free methods for recurrent nets ([citation](http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/532_icmlpaper.pdf)).

I was wondering if anyone has tried Hessian-Free for learning sequence to sequence mappings for machine translation. If so, does it work? Is its performance inferior to LSTM's in some way?

Suggestions of other places to post this kind of question are welcome; although, the obvious place - metaoptimize - is currently so slow and spam-ridden I decided to try here first.

Comment: I'm not tremendously confident about this, but I get the sense that the benefits of Hessian-Free methods haven't justified their complexity. For example, see [this keras github issue thread](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/460). The last entry cites another Sutskever paper saying that momentum-accelerated SGD accomplishes many of the same things as HF methods.